# Error:Error: ':' is not a valid resource name character in String.xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using android studio. In String resources file ":" (Colon) is not supporting.

Error: Invalid URL!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use colons, use underscore instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't us a colon. If your string resource is a URL, you will either have to hard code it in your Java or remove "http://" from your string.